# Como Transformar um Bitmap em java.io.file para enviar à Amazon S3

Tags: android, amazon-aws

Estou com problema para enviar um `Bitmap` para a Amazon S3 usando o SDK da própria amazon S3.

Para enviar algo para o Amazon S3 é necessário ser um arquivo, como transformar o `Bitmap` em `java.io.file`para poder enviar através do `TransferObserver`.

Referência:http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/s3transferutility.html

Comment: Se seu problema é **enviar** o bitmap, porque postou o código para **pegá-lo**? E qual o erro que você recebe?

Comment: deixei ali caso haja algum erro na maneira de o pegar, e para assim haver um melhor entendimento dos passos aos quais estou seguindo e justamente não tem um erro pois não sei como faz para enviar um bitmap para a Amazon S3

Comment: Tanto faz como você obtém o bitmap. Mas qual o problema que você está enfrentando ao enviá-lo? Mostre o código e o erro.

Comment: Provavelmente terá que criar um webservice

Comment: Mas usando o sdk da amazon ele já não faz a conexão direta quando cria um cliente de conexão?

Comment: Ao que notei, tenho de passar um File ao invés de um Bitmap porém como o fazer para poder enviar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu também utilizo o SDK da amazon pra fazer upload para a S3 e gravo o `Bitmap` numa pasta no cache do app e depois passo para o SDK.

Algo como:

```
@NonNull
public static File storeOnCache(Context context, Bitmap bitmap) throws IOException {
    File cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
    File file = new File(cacheDir, generateRandomFilename("jpg"));

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);

    out.flush();
    out.close();

    return file;
}
```

Onde o `generateRandomFileName` é um método simples que gera um nome para não ter conflito.

```
@NonNull
public static String generateRandomFilename(@Nullable String extension) {
    return new StringBuilder(50)
            .append(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .append((int) (Math.random() * 10000.0))
            .append(".")
            .append(extension)
            .toString();
}
```

Ai talvez valha a pena ter um tratamento posterior para remover o arquivo ao final do upload.

Utilizando:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ...

File bitmapOnCache = storeOnCache(this, bitmap);
String fileName = bitmapOnCache.getName();

// Dependendo da forma como irá fazer:

ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();

metadata.setContentLength(mTotalFileBytes = bitmapOnCache.length());
metadata.setContentType("image/".concat(getExtension(fileName)));

PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest("BUCKET_NAME", fileName, new FileInputStream(bitmapOnCache), metadata);

AmazonS3Client client = ...

client.putObject(por);
```

Comment: O que passa como parâmetro para o "bitmap = ..."?

Comment: Ali seria o `Bitmap` que você obteve de algum lugar e que precisa enviar pro S3

Comment: Está aparecendo o seguinte `AmazonClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Write error: ssl=0xb7729c70: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer`, está redefinindo o tamanho ou padrão da imagem?